# How can I make a simpler javascript function for the following:

Tags: replace

There has to be a function that can be used that will greatly simplify, codewise, all these very similar replacements. Would like to be able to make a function that could handle this fall all contractions including I've, Could've  etc.

```
    // for can't
    s = s.replace(/cant/g, "ca{n't|n{| }not}");
    s = s.replace(/can't/g, "ca{n't|n{| }not}");
    s = s.replace(/Cant/g, "Ca{n't|n{| }not}");
    s = s.replace(/Can't/g, "Ca{n't|n{| }not}");

    //for can not
    s = s.replace(/can not/g, "ca{n't|{| }not}");
    s = s.replace(/Can not/g, "Ca{n't|{| }not}");


    // for won't
    s = s.replace(/wont/g, "w{on't|ill not}");
    s = s.replace(/won't/g, "w{on't|ill not}");
    s = s.replace(/Wont/g, "W{on't|ill not}");
    s = s.replace(/Won't/g, "W{on't|ill not}");

    // for will not
    s = s.replace(/will not/g, "w{on't|ill not}");
    s = s.replace(/Will not/g, "W{on't|ill not}");


    // for hasn't
    s = s.replace(/hasnt/g, "has{n't| not}");
    s = s.replace(/hasn't/g, "has{n't| not}");
    s = s.replace(/Hasnt/g, "Has{n't| not}");
    s = s.replace(/Hasn't/g, "Has{n't| not}");

    // for has not
    s = s.replace(/has not/g, "has{n't| not}");
    s = s.replace(/Has not/g, "Has{n't| not}");
```

Answer (score 0):

For `can not` and  `can't`, it could be done in a single step:

```
s = s.replace(/(C|c)an(?:'?t| not)/g, "ca{n't|n{| }not}");
```

Or, if you want to match also `cannot`

```
s = s.replace(/(C|c)an(?:'?t| ?not)/g, "ca{n't|n{| }not}");
```

Same principle can be applied for the other `has not` and `will not`

Comment: why cant that same formula be used for all of them?

Comment: @user7212232: It will become unreadable. With that you have only 3 regexes. But it's up to you to combine all the three.